# How can I convert an F# (double -> double) to Func<double, double>?

Tags: f#, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I'm using `MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra` to build a library.  I need to apply a user-specified function to every element of the matrix, for which I know I can use `Map`:

```
open System
open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra
open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double

let m1 = matrix [[1.0; 2.0; 3.0]]
let f1 = fun s -> s * 3.14
let m2 = m1.Map f1 // THIS FAILS
let m3 = m1.Map (fun s -> s * 3.14) // THIS WORKS!
```

In the line for `m2` I get the following error:

```
This expression was expected to have type Func<float, 'a> but here has type double -> double
```

But I need to be able to pass in the mapping function instead of defining it inline as for `m3`.  The documentation for `MathNet.Numerics` does not seem to have an answer to my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct the delegate like this:

```
let m2 = m1.Map (Func<_, _> f1)
```

F# implicitly constructs delegates in some cases, as seen with the lambda in the question, but it's not always seamless. See [the MSDN page for delegates in F#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233206.aspx) for some additional information.

Answer (score 5):

The F# extensions (MathNet.Numerics.FSharp package) usually provide a variant that can handle normal F# functions. In this case, you can write:

```
let m2 = m1 |> Matrix.map f1
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This would go well with the other `map` methods I use, such as `List.map`, etc.